# AdGroupCriterionService isn't changing keyword text

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-ads-api

I've been using this Node Module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleads-node-lib and have been able to change the Tracking Template and the CpcBid microAmount  using it but can't figure out why it doesn't change the keyword text. Relevant code below:

```
var budget = new service.Model(attributes);

// Change Keyword text (doesn't work)
budget.attributes.criterion.text = 'superawesomekeyword';

// Also tried this line below but it doesn't work either.
budget.set('criterion', {'attributes': {'xsi:type': 'Keyword'},
                                        'id': 175369767649,
                                        'type': 'KEYWORD',
                                        'Criterion.Type': 'Keyword',
                                        'text': 'superawesomekeyword', 
                                        'matchType': 'EXACT'})    

// Change CPC Bid <---- This works
budget.attributes.biddingStrategyConfiguration.bids[0].bid.microAmount = 80000000;

// Change Tracking Template URL <---- This also works
budget.set('trackingUrlTemplate', 'http://test.com');

service.mutateSet(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID, budget, function(err, results) {
     if (err) {
         console.log(err);
     }

     else { 
          console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
     }
}
```

Console output showing that the tracking template and microAmount has changed but not the keyword text. [Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doeOw.png)

Comment: If you change keyword text it's like change of keyword, not same ID, isn't it?

Comment: Good point. Yes, changing the keyword text does change the ID. I suppose I can remove the keyword first and then add a new one, although that takes more operations. Is there any way I can just use the Set operator to change the keyword text?

Comment: I believe that you must create new keyword...

Comment: Yep, I ended up going with creating a new keyword and then removing the old one if successful. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new keyword instead of attempting to change it, if keyword creation is successful then remove the old keyword.